# facebook share js sdk about gmail account

Tags: facebook

I found a problem using sdk from facebook js.
When I use gmail account login facebook and share pictures, the picture is display like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w71jy.jpg)

When I use a non-gmail account login facebook and share pictures, the picture is display like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ym2g.jpg)

The picture is 1200 * 630 pixels.
So I'm confused.
I tried several accounts, are in line with this law, is it a facebook bug?

Comment: There is no guarantee to get the large format, Facebook might decide to use the small version based on a multitude of factors. But I doubt this has actually anything to do with whether you use a GMail email address in the account.

Comment: What makes a factor Facebook decided to use a small image version?

Comment: I use the share_open_graph method of the FB.ui interface on Facebook, the action_type is og.likes.

Comment: My code:
FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.likes',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object : {
                    'og:url': shareUrl, // your url to share
                    'og:title': shareName+" on For Fans By Fans",
                    'og:description': shareDescription,
                    'og:image': shareImage,
                    'og:image:width': '1200',
                    'og:image:height': '630'
                }
            })
        }, function(response){
        }